# How to fix a .NET Core CORS error when service is published

Tags: .net-core, cors

I have created simple .NET Core service to send mail from Angular client. In development environment when client and server run on different ports of localhost it works fine, but when service is published at hosting client receives error:

> " has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight
> request doesn't pass access control check: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource."

I have implemented temporarily open policy for test purposes.

In Startup.cs added:

```
services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("OpenPolicy", builder => {   
    builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader();}));
```

and

```
app.UseCors("OpenPolicy");
```

In Controller:

```
[EnableCors("OpenPolicy")]
[Route("api/[controller]")]  
[ApiController]  
public class MailController : ControllerBase
{
    [EnableCors("OpenPolicy")]
    [HttpPost]
    public MailResult SendMessage([FromBody]Mail mail)
    {
        ...
```

Am I missing anything? Can it be hosting configuration?

Comment: This sounds like a relay problem to me, have you checked with your hosting?

Answer (score 0):

This is quite a vague issue maybe you need to allow credentials as well:

```
builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
       .AllowAnyMethod()
       .AllowAnyHeader()
       .AllowCredentials();
```